# How to list files in a directory based on latest time and loop through that file list and save it in an array for pattern matching

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to list the files in a directory based on timestamp. split and add those files in an array then to loop through.

ls -t command lists the latest files but not sure how to split them and store in an array

`ls -t *.ack`

Comment: What do you mean *split*? Elaborate and add more information to your question, it's not really clear what you're asking

Comment: for example if a folder contains, 
one.txt
two.txt
three.txt
and if i use ls -t *.txt then it will list as one.txt two.txt three.txt
all 3 files will be listed with single space. this i will assign in a variable and try to split using single space ' ' and store in an array. but its not happening

Comment: Okay, why do you need them to be sorted by timestamp? Asking because doing it in a robust way is kind of a pain in the rear

Comment: even though there are multiple files with same name and only with different serial number, want to sort based on the latest file uploaded into the server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If that the file name do not have special characters (spaces, wildcard, etc), and if the number of files is small (usually, <1000), you  can use `bash` arrays:

Assuming split mean to break the output of the ls into individual files.

If not, consider using find/xargs.

```
a=($(ls -t))
# A is sorted by timestamp
for file in "${a[@]}" ; do
    Do something with '$file'
    echo $file
done
# Technically, no need for intermediate array. Iterate over the response.
for file in $(ls -t) ; do
    Do something with '$file'
    echo $file
done
```